# In C programming when writing data to a .txt file how to move to next line

Tags: c

I just wanted to print a sequence into a text file. It should actually look like

```
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
ABCDE
ABCDEF
```

But When i write this to a text file it actually appears like
AABABCABCDABCDE``

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
     int num;
     char i,j;
     FILE *fptr;
     fptr = fopen("D:\\passwords.txt","w");
     for(i=665;i<70;i++)
     {
         printf("\n");
         for(j=65;j<=i;j++)
             fprintf(fptr,"%c",j);
     }
     fclose(fptr);
     return 0;
  }
```

Can someone help to write the sequence as it is to the text file..

Comment: `fprintf(fptr, "\n");` at the appropriate place?

Comment: Use `fputc(j,fptr)` instead of your `fprintf` call

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=65;i<70;i++)
 {
     for(j=65;j<=i;j++)
         fprintf(fptr,"%c",j);
     fprint(fptr,"\n");
 }
```

Comment: Better use `fputc(j,fptr);` and `fputc('\n', fptr);` instead of your `fprintf`calls

Answer (score 0):

I have solve your problem.Here is the solution:
When your want to write to file,you use the fprint and the file descriptor which specified the file you want to write.But you use printf to insert the '\n',printf will put the '\n' into the stdout not the file you want insert the '\n'.So Just a little will make your code work correctly.

```
 int num;
 char i,j;
 FILE *fptr;
 fptr = fopen("passwords2.txt","w+");
 for(i=65;i<70;i++)
 {
     fprintf(fptr,"\n");
     for(j=65;j<=i;j++)
         fprintf(fptr,"%c",j);
 }
 fclose(fptr);
 return 0;
```

Comment: Better use `fputc('\n', fptr);` and `fputc(j,fptr);` instead of your `fprintf`calls

Comment: I know fputc is used to put one character into the file stream,but is it better than fprintf.If it is,which point shows fputc is better than fprintf.

Comment: First, `fputc` takes one less argument (so is simpler, and presumably faster). Often `fprintf` is built above `fputc`. Some compilers optimize some calls to `fprintf` (like yours) to calls to `fputc` (or  `fputs` or equivalent). And `fprintf` has to "*interpret*" its format control string `"%c"`. See [stdio documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io)

Comment: Sorry my friend,i am also not a native English speaker,i apologize for what i did.